# Django - how to access request body in a decorator?

Tags: python, django

I need to access the body of a request inside of a decorator, how can i do that?

I'm calling the `cache_page` decorator from `get` in a class based view. In order to perform some logic, i need to access the URL of the request in the decorator.

Here is my code:

```
def custom_cache_page(timeout, *, cache=None, key_prefix=None):
    #print(request)
    return decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheMiddleware)(
        page_timeout=85,
        cache_alias=cache,
        key_prefix=key_prefix,
    )


class Sales_View(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    @method_decorator(custom_cache_page(1.5))
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```

Edit: i tried to do that with `@wraps`

```
def custom_cache_page(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheMiddleware)(
            page_timeout=85,

        )
    return inner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the decorator inside the `custom_cache_page`, like:

```
from functools import wraps

def custom_cache_page(timeout, *, cache=None, key_prefix=None):
    callto = decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheMiddleware)(
        page_timeout=85,
        cache_alias=cache,
        key_prefix=key_prefix,
    )
    def decorator(view):
        @wraps(view)
        def f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request)
            return callto(view)(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return decorator
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried this, but i keep getting 'Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'function'>`

Comment: You did return `callto(request, *args, **kwargs)` right, not `callto` itself?

Comment: Yes. I got the same error when i tried to the same with @wrap(view)

Comment: @JayK23: but exactly where did you apply `@wrap(view)`. Note that `custom_cache_page` itself is not the decorator: `custom_cache_page` is a *function* that *produces* a decorator.

Comment: I just added to the question how i tried with @wraps, sorry for not doing it right away

Comment: @JayK23: but you are not calling the decorator itself. See edit: the `decorator` function takes the view, and thus returns a function `f` that wraps the view and calls the `callto` internally.